# Is there a way to format cells in one column based on the cells in another column for the same row? (openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an Excel Workbook with a sheet that looks like this:

```
Label    Measure    Value
A        Cost       -23.12
A        Percentage 0.357
B        Cost       48.1
C        Location   NY
C        Cost       13
```

What I want to do is format the cells in the `Value` column based on the corresponding cells in the `Measure` column. In this case, if the cell reads "Cost" then the cell in the same row and in the `Value` column should read "$ 23.12" (applying a currency format.) The formatting for `Value` cells when `Measure` is "Percentage" should be percentage, for "Location", text.

The final result would look like:

```
Label    Measure    Value
A        Cost       $ -23.12
A        Percentage 35.7 %
B        Cost       $ 48.10
C        Location   NY
C        Cost       $ 13.00
```

I am using pandas to create this data. I would simply make these changes in the DataFrame before I export to Excel. However there is one other piece of formatting I need to do. I want to highlight all numeric cells in the `Value` column--green if positive and red if negative. But I don't want to touch the cells corresponding to "Location."

I can do something like this:

```
workbook[sheet].conditional_formatting.add('C2:C6', CellIsRule(operator='greaterThan', formula=['0'], fill=green_fill, font=green_font))
workbook[sheet].conditional_formatting.add('C2:C6', CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], fill=red_fill, font=red_font))
```

This works for all cells in row C, but how can I do this this for the specific subset of cells I'm interested in?

Comment: You can use number formats here rather than conditional formatting.